# Why is the order of functions in the tagbar different from the C source file?

Tags: plugin, plugin-tagbar

When opening C/C++ source code in Vim, if you open the tagbar plugin, the display order of functions in the tagbar is different from the display order in the C/C++ source file. I wonder why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both types of sorting are possible:

- Alphabetically (the default)
- By position in the file

You can switch the sorting criteria using the `s` key.

You can control the default using `g:tagbar_sort`.

To make the default to "by position in the file" set:

```
let g:tagbar_sort = 0
```

Remark: For Python class will be always before functions (since tagbar group classes and functions)

Comment: Thank you! I now can control the tagbar sorting. Thank you!

Comment: Thank fie the feedback :-) I'm glad I could help you.